# Insmod string parameter with whitespace

Tags: module, linux-kernel, insmod

hi I learn module these day. Today I write a simple module that would take string parameter when using insmod here is code snippet:

```
....
static char *city = "NULL";
MODULE_PARM(city, charp,0000);
....
```

when I type in command line

```
insmod modulename.ko city="newyork"
```

it's ok

but when I type

```
insmod modulename.ko city="new york"
```

there is error

```
insmod: error inserting 'modulename.ko': -1 Unknown symbol in module
```

do you know why?

Comment: Have you tried 
`insmod modulename.ko city=new\ york` ?

Comment: the city is string should be included in ""@avd